# Do I have to precede a quotation with a comma if the quotation is preceded with "to"?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a blog post and wanted to figure out if the following sentence was grammatically sound.

> Our Sketch above takes a parameter k which roughly translates to "How many users do you want to keep in the Sketch?"

Am I missing a comma? Is the correct form actually

> Our Sketch above takes a parameter k which roughly translates to, "How many users do you want to keep in the Sketch?"

Comment: That's not a quotation. That's referring to words as words. Or, in this case, a phrase as a phrase. Nobody is actually *saying* it. As such, there is no reason for a speech tag. You could also dispense with the quotation marks and use italics instead.

Comment: The following questions don't specifically reference speech or speech tags (so I'm not certain if this is strictly a duplicate of one or the other), but they are at least related.

Comment: [Is there punctuation for words treated as words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456285/is-there-punctuation-for-words-treated-as-words/456297#456297)

Comment: [What is the best way to mention a word: italics, quotes, or single-quotes (apostrophes)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41391/what-is-the-best-way-to-mention-a-word-italics-quotes-or-single-quotes-apost/142028#142028)

Comment: [How should you punctuate the construction of “She read until she reached the word x.”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288601/how-should-you-punctuate-the-construction-of-she-read-until-she-reached-the-wor/288609#288609)

Comment: Also, *k* probably doesn’t translate to a question.  It represents the *answer* to a question.  So, “Our Sketch above takes a parameter k which represents the number of users that should be kept in the Sketch.”

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This is my first time posting a grammar question and I find the responses fascinating.