# When an entire article is about a word, should that word be in quotation marks on first reference?

Tags: quotation-marks

When an entire article is about a word, should that word be in quotation marks on first reference?

I'm editing a piece about the word "grit." I'm wondering whether to put it in quotation marks in the first sentence, as it's used in virtually every sentence thereafter, and I wouldn't want to use quotation marks throughout.

The first sentence is –

> [Name] defines grit as the combination of passion and perseverance.

Comment: I'd set it in italics throughout, as per the advice of the Chicago Manual of Style (shown in SvenYargs' answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/379315/)).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your style guide, whether or not the word is well known, and whether or not the word is contentious.

Your style guide or publication may have rules for such things.  For instance, on Wikipedia, the subject of the article is put in bold the first time it's used.  In other cases, one would italicize the first use.

If your editor or style guide has no such rule, you could still choose to put the word in quotes the first time it's used, because you are quoting the word, albeit from an abstract, undefinable source.

The [APA style guide](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/use-double-quotes.aspx) recommends using quotes the first time you use a term that is "ironic," "slang," or "self-coined."

Publications like *The New York Times* use quotation marks upon first use with words or terms that are contentious or lack a well-known definition.  This can also be done when the word is used in the context of a definition.  For example, [see this article on the term "deep state."](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/06/us/politics/deep-state-trump.html?_r=0):

> a White House preoccupation with a “deep state” working to thwart the Trump presidency.

Here it is in quotes because it is both contentious and not widely known.

In the second paragraph it is put in quotes again, because it is being defined.

> The concept of a “deep state”... is...

Subsequent uses do not use quotation marks:

> he has spoken with Mr. Bannon many times about his suspicion of the deep state and what he sees as its pernicious influence.

The rule can also vary depending on whether you are publishing in print or online.  Occasionally online articles will make the first use a link to a definition of the word in a dictionary, or to another explanatory article.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of preference and personal taste. However, I'd have it in italics once, and then just type it as an ordinary word throughout.